# Intellij Idea wrongly consider added zip file to repo as moved from different archive

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij Idea community 2019.2 to work with Git repository.

I added a zip file to the repo, but during the commit, I noticed that this file considered as moved from completely different zip file from other directory of the repository.

[See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxRUW.png)

But the files are different:

awscli-bundle-1.16.314.zip - 19088950 bytes

awsec2monitor-2-1-3.zip - 15495442 bytes

How can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: If you were using Git, instead of the IDE, you could just add `--no-renames` to your `git diff`. I have no idea how you can do this in the IDE, or even *if* you can.

Comment: In git cli I don't have this situation.. But thanks anyway.

Comment: >I added a zip file to the repo

How exactly have you done it? Have you extracted it from your another zip archive? have you done it via IDE or in file explorer?

Comment: Hi Ruslan,
I did it with paste from copied file in file manager (Ubuntu) to target directory in Idea. I also tired to use cp command with terminal - the result is the same.